# Loading XML in Flash AS3

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying to create an application that can show a list of options from an XML.
Then when one option is clicked load data from a different XML to show for the option that they picked which is [j].

The code I have here only goes to the last variable after being put through the loop so no matter which option i click it goes to the data from the last option.
It only removes the last child of the original buttons as well.

Does anybody have any idea how I could get it to go to the right page?

```js
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.text.TextField;

var xmlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var xmlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://praxis2.cit.ie/~patrickhallihan/DynamicContent/autumn/classxml.php");
xmlLoader.load(xmlReq);

xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, getClasses);
function getClasses(e:Event):void
    {
        var xmlobject:XML = new XML(e.target.data);
        var classlist:XMLList = xmlobject.classgroup;
        var classArray:Array = new Array();

        for (var i:int = 0; i<classlist.length(); i++)
            {
                var classname:String = xmlobject.classgroup.classname[i];
                var classtxt:TextField = new TextField();

                classtxt.width = 70;
                classtxt.height = 20;
                classtxt.border = true; 
                classtxt.borderColor = 0x000000;
                classtxt.background = true; 
                classtxt.backgroundColor = 0x888888;
                classtxt.textColor = 0xFFFFFF;
                classtxt.text = "" + classname;
                addChild (classtxt);
                classArray[i] = classtxt;
            }

        for (var j:int = 0; j<classlist.length(); j++)
            {
                classArray[j].y = 40*j;
                classArray[j].x = 125;
                classArray[j].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoSchedule);

                function gotoSchedule(event:MouseEvent):void
                    {
                        removeChild (classtxt);

                        var xmlLoader1:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
                        var xmlReq1:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://praxis2.cit.ie/~patrickhallihan/DynamicContent/autumn/getschedule.php?id="+ j);
                        xmlLoader1.load(xmlReq1);

                        xmlLoader1.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, getExams);
                        function getExams(e:Event):void
                            {
                                trace (xmlLoader1.data);
                                var examtxt:TextField = new TextField();
                                examtxt.width = 260;
                                examtxt.height = 400;
                                examtxt.y = 30;
                                examtxt.x = 30;
                                examtxt.border = true; 
                                examtxt.borderColor = 0x000000;
                                examtxt.background = true; 
                                examtxt.backgroundColor = 0x888888;
                                examtxt.textColor = 0xFFFFFF;
                                examtxt.text = (xmlLoader1.data);
                                addChild (examtxt);
                            }
                    }
            }
    }
```

Comment: At first glace looks like it should work, have you confirmed that your http://praxis2.cit.ie/~patrickhallihan/DynamicContent/autumn/getschedule.php?id=2 returns the right stuff?   Also, no need for two seperate for loops

Comment: i've gotten rid of the second loop but it is still doing the same thing. yeah thats the right address for the xml it is getting it and displaying it but only the one for the last index so no matter which i click it brings back the data that the last one should

Comment: Sorry didn't mean to give you the impression that the second loop was a problem, just a general coding tip that it's unnecessary.

Comment: its grand just trying to figure it out myself in college at the moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this will fix your problem (refactored your code), but it's cleaner not to have some many anonymous function inside of other functions.  Plus you totally don't need a second for loop.

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.text.TextField;

var classArray:Array = new Array();    

var xmlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var xmlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://praxis2.cit.ie/~patrickhallihan/DynamicContent/autumn/classxml.php");

xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, getClasses); //add your listeners BEFORE you call load
xmlLoader.load(xmlReq);

function getClasses(e:Event):void
{
    var xmlobject:XML = new XML(e.target.data);
    var classlist:XMLList = xmlobject.classgroup;

    for (var i:int = 0; i<classlist.length(); i++)
    {
        var classname:String = xmlobject.classgroup.classname[i];
        var classtxt:TextField = new TextField();

        classtxt.width = 70;
        classtxt.height = 20;
        classtxt.border = true; 
        classtxt.borderColor = 0x000000;
        classtxt.background = true; 
        classtxt.backgroundColor = 0x888888;
        classtxt.textColor = 0xFFFFFF;
        classtxt.text = "" + classname;
        addChild (classtxt);
        classArray[i] = classtxt;

        classtxt.y = 40 * i;
        classtxt.x = 125
        classtxt.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoSchedule);
    }
}    

function getIndexFromTextField(tf:TextField):int {
    for (var i:int = 0; i < classArray.length; i++) {
        if (classArray[i] == tf) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

function gotoSchedule(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var tf:TextField = event.currentTarget as TextField;
    removeChild(tf);

    xmlLoader = new URLLoader();
    var xmlReq1:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://praxis2.cit.ie/~patrickhallihan/DynamicContent/autumn/getschedule.php?id=" + getIndexFromTextField(tf));
    xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, getExams);
    xmlLoader.load(xmlReq1);
}

function getExams(e:Event):void
{
    trace(xmlLoader.data);
    var examtxt:TextField = new TextField();
    examtxt.width = 260;
    examtxt.height = 400;
    examtxt.y = 30;
    examtxt.x = 30;
    examtxt.border = true; 
    examtxt.borderColor = 0x000000;
    examtxt.background = true; 
    examtxt.backgroundColor = 0x888888;
    examtxt.textColor = 0xFFFFFF;
    examtxt.text = (xmlLoader.data);
    addChild(examtxt);
}
```

Comment: i"m getting an Access of undefined property xmlLoader1 in the last function

Comment: my bad, you have to move out of the function as a global variable. I'll update the code

Comment: Did this help with your problem?